# Mysql ORDER BY FIELD is there a way to get the same value more times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT stopName
     , stopId 
  FROM Stations 
 WHERE stopId IN ( 2845, 1380, 1433, 1434
                 , 2965, 2966, 2676, 2322
                 , 2323, 1405, 2845) 
 ORDER 
    BY FIELD( stopId, 2845, 1380, 1433, 1434
                    , 2965, 2966, 2676, 2322
                    , 2323, 1405, 2845);
```

The stopId 2845 is repeated twice and with this query i only get the first 2845 row. Is there a way to get the same row multiple times in this order??

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Why is StopId repeating the first place? Is it something like the traveler ends where he started?

Comment: @SalmanA yes it is a bus line. I think is better to handle the data display on my application code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IN` operator does not generate records; it is a logical operator that lets you *filter* the content of the table.

One solution would be to use a derived table and join it with the original table (if you have a large list of values, this will painful...):

```
select s.stopName, s.stopId
from (
    select 2845 stopId, 1 seq
    union all select select 1380, 2
    ...
    union all select select 2845, 10
) t
inner join stations s on s.stopId = t.stopId
order by t.seq
```